# Is it possible to isolate cells harboring a specific DNA sequence?

Tags: cell-biology

Suppose on cell subpopulation harbours within its genome a specific DNA sequence that do not exist in other cell subpopulations. Is it technically possible to isolate such subpopulation ? and if yes, how ?

Some additional information about the cells. All different subpopulations are B-cells. But only one of these subpopulation harbors a specific DNA sequence. We do not think that this sequence is transcribed, and if so in a very lowly expressed manner. We also know that this sequence is only present in one of the two alleles. The main idea of this experiment is to follow this subpopulation at different time points. As the relative abundance of this subpopulation compared to the whole B-cell population is low, we wanted to isolate them in order to study them (DNA mutation, RNA expresion, etc...)

Thanks

Comment: If you can distinguish these cells from other cells somehow, yes, there are possibilities.

Comment: The sequence you're trying to find, is it something you're inserting in the organism, and you want to find which have accepted the sequence, or is this an arbitrary sequence?

Comment: All the cell subpopulations (say subpop A, B and C) are part of the same cell type (in my case T-cells). And subpop A harbos the specific DNA sequence (~50-100nt long).And the sequence is not something that I insert into the cell.

Comment: @NicoBxl Is the sequence in population A transcribed? In my mind, staining for a specific mRNA sequence would be a lot easier than looking for a DNA sequence, especially because of signal amplification. For DNA, there are at most 2 sequences per cell (assuming the cell is homozygous), while there could theoretically be tens to hundreds to thousands of mRNA copies per cell. Please [edit] your question and include as much detail as possible about your cells and the sequence you're trying to detect (obviously, you can anonymize specific genes or whatever if necessary).

Comment: I can't think of any such technique off hand. Would it be more convenient in your case to genetically engineer the cells to include that specific DNA sequence instead?

Comment: @MarchHo No it's not possible as we have mutliple in-vivo samples (differents time points). We do not want to have an artifical scenario (even if might be a interesting idea to dig into)

Comment: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0113549 here's an interesting technique

Comment: The only technique I can think of off the top of my head is [FISH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence_in_situ_hybridization).